# How can I avoid to use mysql function in this sql？

Tags: mysql

I seem to be facing an awkward situation that use TIMESTAMPDIFF function in mysql‘s query conditions. Resoures show me it could reduce execution efficiency，but I am curious about how should I proceed.

The following is my sql

```
SELECT personTotal.person_id
FROM personTotal
         LEFT JOIN p2
                   ON p2.person_id = personTotal.person_id
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR , personTotal.through_time, p2.through_time) < 20
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could phrase the `WHERE` clause to use addition with an `INTERVAL`:

```sql
SELECT p1.person_id
FROM personTotal p1
LEFT JOIN p2
    ON p2.person_id = p1.person_id
WHERE
    p1.through_time + INTERVAL 20 HOUR > p2.through_time;
```

The above query's `WHERE` clause, in addition to not using a date function, is also *sargable*, meaning that any index on the date columns of the two tables can be used here.  The version you have above with `TIMESTAMPDIFF` is not sargable, and can't use an index.

Comment: will it really use an index on p1.through_time?  I thought you would have to make it `p1.through_time > p2.through_time - INTERVAL 20 HOUR` for that.

Comment: I guess it depends on which index is wanted here, as written, going by your comment, the `WHERE` clause _could_ use an index on `p2.through_time`.